# value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Weather]

Tags: apache-spark

this code is normal in spark-shell,
but it is abnomal in Intellj IDE.

this is Error message.
Error:(59, 7) value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Weather]
    possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value toDF'?
    }.toDF()

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StandardScaler
import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.RegressionEvaluator
import org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.ParamGridBuilder

import org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

case class Weather(
                date: String,
                day_of_week: String,
                avg_temp: Double,
                max_temp: Double,
                min_temp: Double,
                rainfall: Double,
                daylight_hours: Double,
                max_depth_snowfall: Double,
                total_snowfall: Double,
                solar_radiation: Double,
                mean_wind_speed: Double,
                max_wind_speed: Double,
                max_instantaneous_wind_speed: Double,
                avg_humidity: Double,
                avg_cloud_cover: Double)

case class Tracffic(date: String, down: Double, up: Double)
case class Predict(describe: String, avg_temp: Double, rainfall: Double, weekend: Double, total_snowfall: Double)

object weather2 {
  def main(args : Array[String]): Unit = {
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("weather2")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val weatherCSVTmp = sc.textFile("D:\\shared\\weather.csv")
val weatherHeader = sc.parallelize(Array(weatherCSVTmp.first))
val weatherCSV = weatherCSVTmp.subtract(weatherHeader)
val weatherDF = weatherCSV.map(_.split(",")).map { p =>
  Weather(p(0),
    p(1),
    p(2).trim.toDouble,
    p(3).trim.toDouble,
    p(4).trim.toDouble,
    p(5).trim.toDouble,
    p(6).trim.toDouble,
    p(7).trim.toDouble,
    p(8).trim.toDouble,
    p(9).trim.toDouble,
    p(10).trim.toDouble,
    p(11).trim.toDouble,
    p(12).trim.toDouble,
    p(13).trim.toDouble,
    p(14).trim.toDouble)
}.toDF()//error

val tracfficCSVTmp = sc.textFile("D:\\shared\\tracffic_volume.csv")
val tracfficHeader = sc.parallelize(Array(tracfficCSVTmp.first))
val tracfficCSV = tracfficCSVTmp.subtract(tracfficHeader)
val tracfficDF = tracfficCSV.map(_.split(",")).map { p =>
  Tracffic(p(0),
    p(1).trim.toDouble,
    p(2).trim.toDouble)
}.toDF() //error

val tracfficAndWeatherDF = tracfficDF.join(weatherDF, "date")
val isWeekend = udf((t: String) =>
  t match {
    case x if x.contains("Sunday") => 1d
    case x if x.contains("Saturday") => 1d
    case _ => 0d
  })
val replacedtracfficAndWeatherDF = tracfficAndWeatherDF.withColumn(
  "weekend", isWeekend(tracfficAndWeatherDF("day_of_week"))
).drop("day_of_week")
val va = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols {
  Array("avg_temp", "weekend", "rainfall")
}.setOutputCol("input_vec")

val scaler = new StandardScaler().setInputCol(va.getOutputCol).setOutputCol("scaled_vec")
va.explainParams
scaler.explainParams

//down predict
val lr = new LinearRegression().setMaxIter(10).setFeaturesCol(scaler.getOutputCol).setLabelCol("down")
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(va, scaler, lr))
val pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(replacedtracfficAndWeatherDF)
val test = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  Predict("Ussally Day", 20.0, 20, 0, 0),
  Predict("Weekend", 20.0, 20, 1, 0),
  Predict("Cold day", 3.0, 20, 0, 20)
)).toDF //error
val predictedDataDF = pipelineModel.transform(test)
val desAndPred = predictedDataDF.select("describe", "prediction").collect()
desAndPred.foreach {
  case Row(describe: String, prediction: Double) =>
    println(s"($describe) -> prediction = $prediction")
}
```

what is the problem? Libraries is spark 2.11.x. would you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the below code and try

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
```

Comment: OMG~ thank you!!!  I'm sorry, would you explain what is reason ?

Comment: of course~ good

Comment: as you are using ide IntelliJ or eclipse you need to explicitly import those packages. The sqlcontext.implicits class contains toDF method in scala to convert the rdd to dataframe. In shell it’s already imported as part of the env. This requirement for scala not for java and python