# value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K, V)]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Note:Suggestions given in answers of below questions are not working
[value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704831/value-todf-is-not-a-member-of-org-apache-spark-rdd-rdd)
[value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Weather]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52261998/value-todf-is-not-a-member-of-org-apache-spark-rdd-rddweather)

I am trying to write a generic function that only keeps top k value for each key in given dataset :

Below is the code:

```
def topKReduceByKey[K:ClassTag,V:Ordering](ds: Dataset[(K, V)], k: Int): Dataset[(K, V)] = {
    import sqlContext.implicits._
    ds
      .rdd
      .map(tuple => (tuple._1, Seq(tuple._2)))
      .reduceByKey((x, y) => (x ++ y).sorted(Ordering[V].reverse).take(k))
      .flatMap(tuple => tuple._2.map(v => (tuple._1, v)))
      .toDF("key", "value")
      .as[(K, V)]
  }
```

On running this I get below error message :

```
Error:(43, 8) value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K, V)]
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value toDF'?
      .toDF("key", "value")
```

can anyone help me understand what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways for doing this(group by, partition by, iterating partitons), but going to RDD should only be the case when you like to have a custom partitioning, for anything else you should stay with Dataframe or Datasets.

I will provide a Python version, using Dataframes. This should be a good starting example for Scala with Datasets(the API is the same).

```
def topKByColumn(df, group_column, ordering_column, k):
    window = Window.partitionBy(df[group_column]).orderBy(df[ordering_column].desc())
    top_k = df.withColumn('rank', row_number().over(window))
    top_k = top_per[top_k.rank <= k]
    return top_k
```

Comment: I knew this approach,but in my case partitioning by key is not a good idea because some keys may be more skewed.I found reduce by key is more optimal approach performance wise and would be happy if some one could suggest the solution to the error at final step of converting to df.

Comment: Before you go on with this solution I just want to emphasize the fact that reduceByKey should be used when the end result is of the same type as the types being reduced. In your case the end result is a list. You should use combineByKey. Also you are using sorted. This will put the entire list in the reducers memory, hence you can end up out of memory on that reduces(if your data is skewed the chances for this are great).